# HTTP Messages only downstream?

Tags: http, protocols

What does it means that http messages only flow downstream?, what would be upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide context for the claim if there's any hope of explaining what the author meant. As written, it's not an accurate statement.

Comment: The text i am referring to is [Http: the definitive guide](http://www.amazon.com/HTTP-Definitive-Guide-David-Gourley/dp/1565925092/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1310111045&sr=8-1), in page 44 it says. "HTTP messages flow like rivers. All messages flow downstream, regardless of whether
they are request messages or response messages"

Comment: The book is simply using that metaphor to define what they mean when they say "downstream." Basically, they're saying that in their usage of the terminology the *sender* is always upstream of the "recipient" who is therefore *downstream* of the sender.